# When next goroutine is executed?

Tags: go, goroutine

I am looking at the example from https://blog.golang.org/pipelines:

```
func main() {
    in := gen(2, 3)

    // Distribute the sq work across two goroutines that both read from in.
    c1 := sq(in)

    // When does this line below execute and what is in `in`?
    c2 := sq(in)

    // Consume the merged output from c1 and c2.
    for n := range merge(c1, c2) {
        fmt.Println(n) // 4 then 9, or 9 then 4
    }
}
```

When does `c2 := sq(in)` run? As what I understand, it executes not when previous line finishes, but instantly as that is a goroutine.

Will `c2` receive the next incoming message that is after coming after the message that is received by `c1`?

Comment: No, it executes when the previous line finishes. There's no `go`, so it's not a goroutine. (The `gen` function may *start* a goroutine, but that's entirely separate and runs in the background.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not use goroutines, in order to use go routines you should  do something like this:

```
q := make(chan type) 
go sq(in, q)
go sq(in, q)

for elem := range q {
    fmt.Println(elem)
}
```

and sq must return the value through a channel

```
func sq(in type, q chan type) {
     ...
     q <- valueFromIn
     ...
}
```

Also you can use [WaitGroup](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) to wait for goroutines to finish.